# How can I increase 0000 by 1 and keep formatting?

Tags: php

```
$i=0000;
while($i<=1231)
{
  print "$i";
  $i++;
}
```

I want it to display `0001`,
`0002`,
`0003`,
`0004`,
but instead it prints: 
`0`,
`1`,
`2`

Does anyone know why this isn't working?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 10):

Try using `printf("%04s",$i);`

Answer (score 4):

```
print str_pad($i,4,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

is only one way... you could also use `sprintf`.

Answer (score 3):

PHP treats the string `0000` as number 0 when considering incrementation. The `++` incrementation operator can actually work on normal strings too, but due to PHP's type handling, it doesn't work as you expect in this case. However, if you had started with string like `a0000`, then incrementing it would result in `a0001`. For example:

```
<?php
$var = 'a0000';
for ($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++)
{
    $var++;
}
echo $var; // Outputs a0100
?>
```

Although, since this method of using the incrementation operator is a bit unorthodox, I would recommend using `printf("%04d", $var)` (or `sprtinf()`) in this case instead, when outputting. For example:

```
<?php
$var = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++)
{
    printf('%04d ', $var);
    $var++;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

sprintf(), str_pad()

Answer (score 1):

try this `$x = str_pad($z + 1, 5, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);`